# How to import my django app's models from command-line?

Tags: python, django

I would like to be able to manipulate my Django app's models via the python console.  I am able to do this with PyCharm but I do not have access to PyCharm in this scenario.  I tried this:

```
[root@myhost scripts]# source /apps/capman/env/bin/activate
(env) [root@myhost scripts]# python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Jan  9 2018, 20:51:20)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> from vc.models import *
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vc.models
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably need to start a Shell first

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then run your

```
from vc.models import *
```

Comment: Thanks! That does it.

Comment: `python manage.py shell_plus` will load your models for you

Comment: For **shell_plus** ==> **pip install django_extensions** and add **'django_extensions',** to settings.py

Comment: Thanks a lot for the `shell_plus` trick; I have been wasting so many hours.

Answer (score 5):

python has a query system called ORM which are python queries based on MYSQL, we can apply these (queriyset) so they are called in django

go to the console and you must go to where your django project is and of course where the manage.py file is located and you will place the following ones:

```
python manage.py shell
```

you will notice that the shell will open there, we must import all our models that we want to perform queryset d as follows:

```
from APPS.models import Class
```

or

```
from .models import *
```

Comment: Just a correction for the future generations, the system is not itself called ORM, an ORM is a type of systems which allows easy intercations with the database without writing queries in a query language like SQL, it is the abbreviation of Object-Relational Mapper.

Comment: There are many ORMs on the market, Django doesn't give it a name so it is Django ORM, for java for example there is Hibernate, Sequelize for Node.js and many other ORMs

Answer (score 3):

## First method

Run in shell:

```bash
python manage.py shell
```

Then, in python console you can import your models:

```py
from users.models import UserModel
```

## Second method

Or from python console run these commands:

```py
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")
django.setup()

# And then import models
from users.models import UserModel
```

> `my_app.settings` is path to your `settings.py`

## Third method

You can run `manage.py shell` from python console also. But in this case you should configure settings the same way as in the second method. This means second method is preferable, but in case you want to use django shell, you should use it like this:

```py
# Run django shell
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'shell'])

# Configure project
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")
django.setup()

# And then import models
from users.models import UserModel
```